# how to find the smallest s to make f continuous at (0,0)

Tags: analysis, continuity

$$ f(x,y)=\left\{
\begin{array}{lll}
\frac{|x|^s|y|^{2s}}{x^2+y^2}  & \text{if}& (x,y) \neq (0,0)\\
0 & \text{otherwise} 
\end{array}
\right. $$

what is the smallest s to make f(x,y) continuous at (0,0)?

Tried: along the line $y=x$, $f$ becomes $\pm x^{3s-2}/2$, so as long as $3s-2>0$, we have $f(0,0)=0$; but along $y=x^2$, $f$ then becomes $\frac{|x|^{5s}}{x^2+x^4}$, if we take the limit, it follows that as long as $5s-2>0$ we will end up with $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x,x^2)=0$...

So I got confused, is it be possible to give the minimum of s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that

$$|x|,|y|\le ||(x,y)||^2$$
so

$$\frac{|x|^s|y|^{2s}}{x^2+y^2}\le ||(x,y)||^{3s-2}\xrightarrow{(x,y)\to(0,0)}0\;\text{if}\; 3s-2>0$$
and notice that for $s=\frac23$ and with the sequences $x_n=y_n=\frac1n$ we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n,y_n)\ne0$$ so to make $f$ continuous we should take $s>\frac23$.

Answer (score 1):

> The critical value is $s=\frac23$.

For $s=\frac23$, $f(x,0)=0$ and $f(x,x)=\frac12$ for every $x\ne0$ hence $f$ has no limit at $(0,0)$.

If $s\gt\frac23$, note that $t^{1/3}\leqslant1+t$ for every nonnegative $t$ hence, for $t=x^2/y^2$, $|x|^{2/3}|y|^{4/3}\leqslant x^2+y^2$. Thus, $f(x,y)\leqslant|x|^{s-2/3}|y|^{2s-4/3}\to0$ when $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ hence $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.